# Set values for all form elements from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form in html and I need to set the values for all the elements in the form .

I have an object like this containing all the names of fields and thier values :-

```
obj= {  
   name:'john',
   age:10,
   Country:'USA'
}
```

Instead of accessing each element of the form and setting the values , Is there any way to set the values directly using jquery or something without much code ?

Whats the easiest way to do this  ?

Comment: Yes, loop over the keys of the object and match them to the names of the elements. Then you can just set their values. If you want more specific help on exactly how to do that, show us what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 5):

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    $(`input[name="${key}"]`).val(obj[key]);
})
```

This loops through each object property, findes the input with the same name as the object property key, and sets its value to the property value

https://jsfiddle.net/53kjnunj/

Comment: Doesn't fill, areaboxes and select fields, works well with input boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for setting data from object to form elements

```
function loadFormElements(form, data ) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        var element = $(form).find("input[name='" + index + "']");

        if( $(element).is(":checkbox") ) {
            if( value == "Y" ) {
                $(element).prop('checked',value == "Y" );
            } else {
                $(element).removeProp('checked' );
            }
        } else {
            element.val(value);
        }
    });
}
```

Call the above method as below

```
  loadFormElements( $("#myform"),obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without jQuery like this:

```
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="name">
      <input type="text" id="age">
      <input type="text" id="country">
    </form>
```

JS:

```
obj= {  
   name:'john',
   age:10,
   Country:'USA'
}

document.getElementById('name').value = obj.name;
document.getElementById('age').value = obj.age;
document.getElementById('country').value = obj.Country;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/292bcxux/

Comment: I think the idea is to use the object property name to target a input....

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is asking to *avoid*.